# Apache Virtual Host Localhost

Tags: apache, web, localhost, virtualhost

Hi my problem is when I try to access my localsite's url, I do not get directed properly. Here is my setup:

`/var/www/example.com` has all the code

/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

and finally my /etc/hosts

```
# This file is automatically generated by WSL based on the Windows hosts 
file:
# %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Modifications to this file will be 
overwritten.
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

When I ping example.com I get

```
PING example.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.392 ms
```

But when I go to http://example.com it is just the normal domain site. I cleared cache on Chrome and I

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is just the normal domain site" ?

Comment: You specified DocumentRoot to html folder it should be to example.com inside www

Comment: @PrathameshPalav I do not get redirected, as if I am going to example.com. I changed the documentroot but I when I still go to example.com it is not my localhost

Comment: You can follow the steps in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

I am running this on Windows. So in the tutorial [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), Step 6 did not work for me (Step Six — Set Up Local Hosts File (Optional)). What I had to do was open Start Menu, search 'Notepad', right click, 'open as admin', open file, go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add example.com here. Once I do that I get redirected to my localhost. Thank you, @PrathameshPalav for the help!